# Как передать объект  в другую область видимости?

Tags: c#, namespace, события

Доброго времени суток.
История такая. Создаются несколько объектов в блоке обработки события (    button_Click    ), оформляются в коллекцию. Её нужно обрабатывать в блоке обработки другого события (    listBox_SelectedIndexChanged    ). Как можно её во втором блоке сделать видимой? (Ошибка:коллекция не существует в текущем контексте)
Пример:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Type1 ob1 = new Type1();//Type1 - public
    Type1 ob2 = new Type2();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList() { ob1, ob2 };
  }
  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    foreach(Type1 obj in list) { obj.Method(); }
    //здесь list не видна
    //но глобально её определять не хочется
  }
}
```

Comment: @LXA, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: 2 DreamChild, пардон, 
обоим, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если по-хорошему, то сама по себе логика, засунутая в обработчики событий - это очень дурная практика. От этого нужно уходить, реализуя какой-либо из паттернов для отделения логики от представления (MVC, MVP, MVVM). Это отдельная большая тема, поэтому если необходимо быстрое решение, то самый логичный вариант - просто добавить в класс формы необходимое свойство, с которым можно будет работать из любого метода. Однако, еще раз повторю, по-хорошему нужно именно отделять логику от обработчиков событий, иначе получите то, что называют антипаттерном Smart UI. Ну и еще пару слов о коде:

1. Забудьте о существовании всяких там ArrayList. В C# уже давным-давно есть обобщённые типы.
2. **foreach(Type1 obj in list) { this.Method(); }** - Итерация по коллекции без использования самих итерируемых элементов выглядит странно
3. подумайте о стиле именования - все эти **button1_Click**, **Type1** и прочие - тоже плохой признак

Comment: Относительно:
2. foreach(Type1 obj in list){obj.Method();}, если речь об этом (спасибо, поправлю);
3. Это по замыслу было сделано для упрощения.

Comment: >Это по замыслу было сделано для упрощения

что именно это упрощает? Скорее наоборот, запутывает. Если в маленьком проекте еще можно держать всю эту кашу из button1_click в голове, то в более-менее крупном проекте вы замучаетесь вспоминать, чем button15_click отличается от button16_click

Comment: Пример на форуме содержит один button_click, всем понятно, о чем речь, другого смысла они тут не несут. В проекте - согласен.

Comment: @LXA речь не о примере в этом вопросе, а вообще о подобной практике. Многие неопытные программисты грешат подобными вещами. К сожалению, писать чистый код не учат даже в институтах, готовящих программистов. Если вам очевидна ошибочность такого стиля, то искренне рад за вас

Answer (score 0):

Если не обращать внимания на странности кода....
Добавьте поле класса, и пусть методы общаются через него:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private ArrayList list;

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Type1 ob1 = new Type1();//Type1 - public
    Type1 ob2 = new Type2();
    list = new ArrayList() { ob1, ob2 };
  }
  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if(list==null) return;//первый обработчик еще не сработал - просто выходим
    foreach(Type1 obj in list) { this.Method(); }        
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, это сработало чисто, спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

нужно определить собственные аргументы события. Что то типа:

```
public class ListEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public List ListObj {get;set;}
}
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, ListEventArgs e)
{
  foreach(Type1 obj in e.ListObj) { this.Method(); }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Кармы - позеленить - не хватит.
Однако в дизайнере появилась ошибка: "Ни одна перегрузка для "listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" не соответствует делегированному "System.EventHandler"".
Это из-за того, что передаю данные в событие? Нужно ли использовать EventHandler<TEventArgs>?

Comment: @Иван Навознов к сожалению, это не самый лучший вариант - вы здесь нарушаете конртвариативность делегатов, отчего этот код повалится с ошибкой. Вводить типы, производные от EventArgs имеет смысл в случае создания нового события. Здесь же используется уже существующее событие SelectedIndexChanged, у обработчиков которого уже есть определенная сигнатура

Comment: @DreamChild, согласен.